# PHPWord - how to add horizontal line to docx/odt document

Tags: php, docx, phpword, odt

I'd started to use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to generate DOCX/ODT from my PHP application.

While it mostly works "out of the box" for me, there is an issue, while trying to add "Horizontal line" to my generated document.

This code just adds nothing, and I can't figure out what's the problem:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addLine(array('dash' => 'dash', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 2, 'weight' => 10));

$phpWord->save(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/test.odt', 'ODText'); // it won't display horizontal line in DOCX either
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Which version of phpword are you using? The above code works fine for docx in 0.12.0. Not visible in odt for me neither...

Comment: @ejuhjav I'm using 0.12.0 form GitHub cloned in June 26

Comment: $phpWord->save(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/test.docx', 'Word2007'); is not working for you?

Comment: @ejuhjav It does saving the file but with no sign of horizontal line :)

Comment: duh, that works for me... have you tested whether the addLine examples from 'samples/Sample_29_Line.php' produce something or are the lines missing from those as well? If those fail to produce any lines maybe you could try opening the files with some other editor (in case you haven't tried that option already). Otherwise I'm a bit out of suggestions

Comment: @ejuhjav I'd actually tried samples as well but with the same result. Maybe OS/word processor issue? I'm running under Debian 7.8 with LibreOffice. Where do you opened your DOCX?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82502/discussion-between-ejuhjav-and-samuel).